# How to find if the sum of periodic function is periodic?

Tags: calculus, terminology

Basically, I am suppose to check if $f(x)=f(x+T)$.

however my function is a bit complex:

$x(t)=10\cos(20000\pi t)+0.5\cos(24000\pi t)+0.5\cos(16000\pi t)$

How shall I check if this function is periodic? doing it by  $f(x)=f(x+T)$ seems very hard.

Comment: It is periodic, since you can check that $x(t+1)=x(t)$. The problem may be to find the **smallest** period. That is harder.

Comment: The problem is just to check if it's periodic than find the T (period time). yet, i don't see how i am suppose to solve it with the f(x)=f(x+T). it's not as simple as it seems.

Comment: Well, as I pointed out, $1$ is a period, so it is periodic. You can also verify that there are smaller periods, for example $\frac{1}{2000}$. Whether there are smaller ones than that takes some work.

Comment: why is x(t+1)=x(t) suppose to be true?

Comment: @user148785 $10\cos(20000\pi(t+1))=10\cos(20000\pi t+2\pi\cdot 1000)=10\cos(20000\pi t)$; similarly for the others.

Comment: is it an alternative known method as: f(x)=f(x+T)? im still having trouble understanding it. it is known the cos is pereiodic but why does it proof that cos+cos+cos is periodic?

Answer (score 1):

My try:

$u=4000t\pi$

$$x(u)=10\cos{5u}+0.5\cos{6u}+0.5\cos{4u}$$

Using:
$$\cos \theta + \cos \varphi = 2 \cos\left( \frac{\theta + \varphi} {2} \right) \cos\left( \frac{\theta - \varphi}{2} \right)$$
You have:

$$\cos 6u + \cos 4u = 2 \cos\left( \frac{6u + 4u} {2} \right) \cos\left( \frac{6u - 4u}{2} \right)$$
$$\cos 6u + \cos 4u = 2 \cos\left( 5u \right) \cos\left( u \right)$$

Replacing:
$$x(u)=10\cos{5u}+\cos{5u}\cos{u}$$
$$x(u)=\cos{5u}(10+\cos{u})$$

The period of that in $u$ time is $T_u=2\pi$ so 
$$T=\frac{2\pi}{4000\pi}=\frac{1}{2000}$$

Comment: can you explain how from x(u)=cos5u(10+cosu) you got this: T=2π/4000π

Comment: The period in the variable $u$ is $2\pi$. So to pass to the period in the variable $t$ you have to divide for $4000\pi$

Answer (score 0):

*Hints:*

- If $T>0$ is a period of $f$, then so is $nT$ for any $n\in\mathbb N$.
- If $T>0$ is a period of both $f_1$ and $f_2$, then it is also a period of $f_1+f_2$.
- Since $2\pi$ is a period of $\cos$, $\frac1{10000}$, $\frac1{12000}$, $\frac1{8000}$ are periods of your summands

Comment: yes but i need to prove that x(t) is periodic.. that is not given.